# Pandas: Reading Excel with merged row cells

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I tried to clean the data as tabular by using pandas and the data is an excel file. The problem is merged row cell which is a type of data. I want to transpose it as a new column to classify the data.

What I'm Facing
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSM0P.png)
What I'm expected.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oi73F.png)

```
What I'm Facing

        Sample   CD4     CD8
---------Group1-------------           
Day 1   8311    17.3    6.44
Day 2   8312    13.6    3.50
Day 3   8321    19.8    5.88
---------Group2------------- 
Day 1   8322    13.5    4.09
Day 2   8311    16.0    4.92
Day 3   8312    5.67    2.28
---------Group3------------- 
Day 1   8321    13.0    4.34
Day 2   8322    10.6    1.95
Day 3   8312    5.67    2.28

What I'm expected.

        Sample   CD4     CD8    Group        
Day 1   8311    17.3    6.44    Group1
Day 2   8312    13.6    3.50    Group1
Day 3   8321    19.8    5.88    Group1
Day 1   8322    13.5    4.09    Group2
Day 2   8311    16.0    4.92    Group2
Day 3   8312    5.67    2.28    Group2
Day 1   8321    13.0    4.34    Group3
Day 2   8322    10.6    1.95    Group3
Day 3   8312    5.67    2.28    Group3
```

Comment: Is it an excel file or text file?

Comment: @Corralien it is an excel file. Teacher assigned to use only panda for clean data and make as a report.

Comment: What is your code so far? What have you tried?

Comment: @TCMolenaar I want to transpose Group1,2,3and 4 as a new role that I'm expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if transposing is the best way to go... As you have not showed us your excel file... I used example as per image below...

I am not a pro, so my approach is not perfect.
The code will read data in a small chunks per each group and combine all to main dataframe.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('TestData.xlsx') # all data to df

# finding rows containing substring "Group" in the first column
indices = df[df['Unnamed: 0'].str.contains('Group')].index.tolist()

# creating empty dataframe for future data 
masterDF = pd.DataFrame()  


# looping initial dataframe
for i in range(len(indices)):
    # slicing df from first indice to the last one
    # or, in other words,
    # reading the source excel file in chunks per each indice
    try:
        data = df.loc[indices[i]: indices[i + 1] - 1, :].copy()
    except IndexError:
        data = df.loc[indices[i]:, :].copy()

    # adding new Columns for each group
    data['Group'] = data.iloc[0,0]
    print(data.iloc[0,0])
    print(data)
    print('end_______________')

    # now appending each chunk of data to the main dataframe
    masterDF = pd.concat([masterDF, data])

# cleaning up dataframe before spitting out to .csv
masterDF.dropna(subset=['Sample', 'CD4', 'CD8'], how='all', inplace=True)  # dropping rows with no data
masterDF.rename(columns={masterDF.columns[0]: ''}, inplace=True)


# spitting out the final data
masterDF.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

out:

```
           Sample    CD4   CD8   Group
1   Day 1  8311.0  17.30  6.44  Group1
2   Day 2  8312.0  13.60  3.50  Group1
3   Day 3  8321.0  19.80  5.88  Group1
5   Day 1  8322.0  13.50  4.09  Group2
6   Day 2  8311.0  16.00  4.92  Group2
7   Day 3  8312.0   5.67  2.28  Group2
9   Day 1  8321.0  13.00  4.34  Group3
10  Day 2  8322.0  10.60  1.95  Group3
11  Day 3  8312.0   5.67  2.28  Group3
```